# How do I solve this Distinct SQL Query

Tags: php, sql

```
select DISTINCT IDDetail, NamaProperti, Provinsi, Kota, Area, TipeListing, JenisProperti, Hadapnya, JenisSertifikat, Harga, LT, LB, foto1 from MsProperti as mp, MsSertifikat as ms, MsDetail as md, MsTipeListing mt where md.IDProperti = mp.IDProperti and md.IDSertifikat = ms.IDSertifikat and md.IDTipeListing = mt.IDTipeListing and Provinsi = 'BSD' or Kota = 'BSD' or Area = 'BSD' and AlreadySold = 0 order by IDDetail desc
```

I know without distinct it would give me a lot of same data, then I put DISTINCT after Select for make it only give me 1 same data. But it makes no different.

Any suggest?

And the answer is adding GROUP BY after WHERE query end.
This is the asnwer

```
    select IDDetail, NamaProperti, Provinsi, Kota, Area, TipeListing, JenisProperti, Hadapnya, JenisSertifikat, Harga, LT, LB, foto1
from MsProperti as mp, MsSertifikat as ms, MsDetail as md, MsTipeListing mt
where md.IDProperti = mp.IDProperti and 
md.IDSertifikat = ms.IDSertifikat and 
md.IDTipeListing = mt.IDTipeListing ".$tambahquery." and AlreadySold = 0
group by IDDetail
order by IDDetail desc
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try `group by` instead of `distinct`

Comment: But all the data of this query return is identical like you describe

Comment: Solved, Thanks Jeans.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT`. Like:

```
SELECT 
    IDDetail, 
    NamaProperti, 
    Provinsi, 
    Kota, 
    Area, 
    TipeListing, 
    JenisProperti, 
    Hadapnya, 
    JenisSertifikat, 
    Harga, 
    LT, 
    LB, 
    foto1 
FROM 
    MsProperti as mp, 
    MsSertifikat as ms, 
    MsDetail as md, 
    MsTipeListing mt 
WHERE 
    md.IDProperti = mp.IDProperti AND 
    md.IDSertifikat = ms.IDSertifikat AND 
    md.IDTipeListing = mt.IDTipeListing AND 
    Provinsi = 'BSD' OR 
    Kota = 'BSD' OR 
    Area = 'BSD' AND 
    AlreadySold = 0 
GROUP BY
    IDDetail, 
    NamaProperti, 
    Provinsi, 
    Kota, 
    Area, 
    TipeListing, 
    JenisProperti, 
    Hadapnya, 
    JenisSertifikat, 
    Harga, 
    LT, 
    LB, 
    foto1 
ORDER BY 
    IDDetail DESC
```